# how to get real formula from EXCEL formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
      | A   |  B
------|-----|--------
    1 |  x  |   1
    2 |  y  |   2
    3 |  z  |   3
    4 |  a  |   =B1*B2+B3
```

Imagine the above stuff is part of an excel sheet, and B4 has a formula `=B1*B2+B3`.

Is it possible to extract the real formula from excel formula? i.e. in the above example, the real formula is `a=x*y+z`.

The reason why I want to do the "transformation" is that I have many excel sheets filled with data and formulas, and now I want to quit Excel and use javascript for calculation, so I want to have the real formulas.

Comment: You do realize that x, y and z are just labels in math. They can be renamed to anything and mean the same thing. So `z=x+y` is the same as `a=b+c` etc. So like `z=x+y` IS `z=B1+B2`. The excel formula IS the real formula.

Comment: You want to get the formula via VBA???

Comment: You could name the ranges: B1 = "x",B2 = "y"... Then your formula would be `=x*y+z`

Comment: You can either select the cell and press `F2` or simply look in the editor window at the top of Excel. If you are using this formula in multiple places though, you may be better off using a name.

Comment: @ Elbert Villarreal via VBA would be acceptable, any kind of suggestions are welcomed, just looking for a solution which is best suited for me. re-type all the formula manually would be extremely time consuming.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you for your comment, I've tried your advice, name ranges first , but excel formula remains to be in "reference"-style instead of "name"-style.

Comment: @D.Yang - just to be clear ... the formula expression in excel is written `=B1*B2+B3` and what you want to extract is `1*2+3`? You want to extract the values that the cell references are working with in the actual formula?

Comment: @ScottCraner Your method would work, but you would have to go re-write all of the formulas with the names instead of cell references. But this could be a solution

Comment: @ScottHoltzman what I want to extract is a=x*y+z

Comment: @D.Yang - will there always be specific variable / letters associated with the formula? or do you just need the formula structure placed into a `a=x*y+z`. Also what if the formula is a `vlookup` or `sumif` or `countif`? Better yet, can you place a screenshot with a few of the formulas you want to convert and what you expect to see after the transformation?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman  no vlookup,sumif or countif, only ordinary formula `+ - * / ^ `and `sqrt()`.  as you can see in the question,  each number has a letter which located next to it, and no duplicate letter allowed in my excel sheet, so yes, there will always be specific letter associated with the formula. What I really need is THE string `a=x*y+z`, and this string will be be evaluated by a javascript application.

Comment: @D.Yang - I think VBA is the only way to do what you want. I have provided a solution as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After defining what it is that you are after, I think a VBA solution is the way to go. And since you noted that it was acceptable, I have provided one for you.

The following Function will return the string `a=x*y+z` and will work so long as all your formulas are set up exactly in the manner given in your example.

```
Function ListRealFormula(rng As Range, ws As Worksheet) As String
Dim sFormula As String
sFormula = rng.Offset(, -1) & rng.Formula

With rng
    Dim d As Range
    For Each d In .DirectPrecedents
        Dim sValue As String, sAdd As String
        sAdd = d.Address(0, 0)
        sValue = ws.Range(sAdd).Offset(, -1).Value2
        sFormula = Replace(sFormula, sAdd, sValue)
    Next
End With

ListRealFormula = sFormula
End Function
```

You can call the function like so:

```
Sub GrabFormula()
Dim s As String

s = ListRealFormula(Sheet1.Range("B4"), Sheet1)
Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

@Wyatt, you have the first part right, but it's not sufficient: once you have clicked the "Show Formulas", you also need to to "Goto Special, Formulas" (Ctrl+G, Special, Formulas). As you have clicked the "Show Formulas", you now do copy/paste into some text editor, and you have all the formulas, used in your Excel sheet.

Comment: another answer best suited as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FORMULATEXT` and `SUBSTITUTE` formulas, so you don't need to deal with VBA.

There's probably a fancier way of doing this with some of the new recursive formula, i don't quite know how to use those yet, but this will work:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(B4),"B1",A1),"B2",A2),"B3",A3)
```

[image]